# How do I set a property to the output of a command in msbuild/xbuild

Tags: msbuild, properties, exec, xbuild

In msbuild/xbuild I'd like to have a "libPath" property which can be ovveridden on the commandline using `/p:libpath="/path/to/all/libs"`. But when this property is undefined I want to call `pkg-config --retrieve-Path somePackage` to get the current systems path.

I thought like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1487887/setting-ant-property-with-bash-command-result) I need the output of a command to be stored in a Property.
The command always returns one line of output.

I have tryied something like

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <LibPath />
</PropertyGroup>

<Task ....>
  <Exec Command="pkg-config --retrieve-Path somePackage"
        Condition="$(LibPath)' == ''">
   <OutputTaskParameter="output"
          PropertyName="LibPath" />
  </Exec>
</Task>
```

But that didn't work.

Comment: It can be done with .Net 4.5. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938679/how-get-exec-task-output-with-msbuild.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that using exec because the Exec task cannot gather output from the tool or command that it runs.

You'll have to write a custom msbuild task that calls pkg-config and gather this output in a property.