# How get exec task output with msbuild

Tags: msbuild, exec, msbuild-task

I'm trying to get simple output by exec task with `msbuild`:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Target Name="Test">
    <Exec Command="echo test output">
      <Output TaskParameter="Outputs" ItemName="Test1" />
    </Exec>
    <Exec Command="echo test output">
      <Output TaskParameter="Outputs" PropertyName="Test2" />
    </Exec>
    <Message Text="----------------------------------------"/>
    <Message Text="@(Test1)"/>
    <Message Text="----------------------------------------"/>
    <Message Text="$(Test2)"/>
    <Message Text="----------------------------------------"/>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

But get next output:

```
  echo test output
  test output
  echo test output
  test output
  ----------------------------------------
  ----------------------------------------
  ----------------------------------------
```

How can I get output by my script?

Comment: seems to be true, thanks I'm miss docuemntation information

Comment: Well documentation is typically not about what isn't possible, but what is. Having that said, your question seems to be common, so maybe you should add appropriate "community content" and thus improve the MSDN documentation.

Comment: aside from the file hack in the Gathering... related post, it doesn't seem like exec can do this very well with exec.  In fact, some people are asking for an improved version in msbuildextensions.

What is it you are trying to do with exec?  There may be an easier way to accomplish whatever you are attempting.  For example, you can get datetime values from the MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Framework.DateAndTime task.  If you really need this functionality, I think building a custom msbuild task would be the best route to go.  I'll try to whip one up when I have some time and post it on here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11096148/msbuild-exec-task-exit-code-empty This link uses <Message Importance="high" Text="$(Test2)"/>

Answer (score 172):

Good news everyone! You can now capture output from `<Exec>` as of .NET 4.5.

Like this:

```
<Exec ... ConsoleToMSBuild="true">
  <Output TaskParameter="ConsoleOutput" PropertyName="OutputOfExec" />
</Exec>
```

Simply:

- Add `ConsoleToMsBuild="true"` to your `<Exec>` tag
- Capture the output using the `ConsoleOutput` parameter in an `<Output>` tag

Finally!

[Documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.build.tasks.exec)

Comment: Can you link to the documentation on this, please?

Comment: Oops, ya.  It's at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms124731(v=VS.110).aspx

Comment: This works with MSBuild 12, which is installed by the Microsoft Build Tools 2013: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40760

Comment: @AviCherry can you please include the link to the documentation in your answer rather than in the comments? Were you able to get this to work in the context of TFS Team Build 2012?

Comment: Updated.  No, I haven't tried it in the context of TFS.

Comment: Great find, @AviCherry! What an oversight that ConsoleToMSBuild ConsoleOutput are missing from the documentation for the Exec task itself (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8zx72cd.aspx).

Comment: @RyanGates- This should be available on a Team Build 2012 server provided either Microsoft Build Tools 2013 (or later) or Visual Studio 2013 (or later) is installed on the server.

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to just redirect the output to variable and not write anything to console output?

Comment: Plus 1 for the Futurama reference. Also, for the great solution ;)

Comment: This is now documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/exec-task

Comment: Also note that by default the console output will still appear in standard out.  If you want to hide it, set `StandardOutputImportance="Low"`.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to capture output to an array-like structure and not to a plain string where the output lines are separated by a semicolon, use **ItemName** instead of **PropertyName**:

```
<Exec ... ConsoleToMSBuild="true">
  <Output TaskParameter="ConsoleOutput" ItemName="OutputOfExec" />
</Exec>
```

Answer (score 7):

I've gotten to the point where I'm so frustrated with the limitations of MSBuild, and the stuff that's supposed to work but doesn't (at least not in every context), that pretty much anytime I need to do anything with MSBuild, I create a custom build task in C#.

If none of the other suggestions are working, then you could certainly do it that way.

Comment: I feel your pain - though my custom task is a python script.

Comment: Understandable but I think MSBuild is more of a structured way to pipe information into the output/error consoles. Although I definitely feel that it's a step above batch files

Comment: I know this is waaaay down the track from when you had this issue, but I just had the same thing happen and resolved it by setting ToolsVersion="12.0" in the root <Project> element.. hope this is of some help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe the output to a file so to speak, and read it back.

```
echo test output > somefile.txt
```