# MSBuild exec task, exit code empty

Tags: msbuild, exec, exit-code

I have the following exec task, performing checkin of assemblyinfo.cs files. I'm trying to return the exit code, but for some reason it is always empty.

```
<!--Checkin if all succeeded-->
<Exec Condition=" '$(LocalCompilationSuccess)' != 'Failed' and '$(LocalTestSuccess)' != 'Failed' " ContinueOnError="True"
              Command='&quot;$(TfCommand)&quot; checkin /recursive /comment:"$(NoCICheckInComment) $(BuildDefinitionName): build succeeded, checkin changes." /override:"TeamBuild $(BuildDefinitionName)" $/SomeProject/Trnk' WorkingDirectory="$(SolutionRoot)"  >
  <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" PropertyName="ErrorCode"/>
</Exec>
```

I've tried to read the exit code in 2 ways:

```
'%(ErrorCode.Identity)'
'$(ErrorCode)'
```

Both are empty. Any suggestions?

Comment: Strange, try out `<Message Text="The exit code is $(ErrorCode)"/>`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In general it works as you have shown.

For reference, here is a more "selfcontained" example:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="4.0">
  <Target Name="help">
    <Exec ContinueOnError="True" Command='cmd.exe /c dir'>
       <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" PropertyName="ErrorCode"/>
    </Exec>
    <Message Importance="high" Text="$(ErrorCode)"/>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

A couple of things you may want to consider however:

- Make sure your `Exec` even executes, that is `Condition` evaluates to
  `True`.
- Output the `ErrorCode` property using the `Message`-Task, to see if it is actually set (to the value you expect). However, make sure MSBuild will show the output, by either using `Importance='high'` or by running `msbuild.exe /v:d` to enable detailed messages.

Comment: Issue caused by condition preventing the method from being invoked. Thanks

Comment: Under mono/xbuild I also had to specify `IgnoreExitCode="true"` in `<Exec>` task for property to be populated.

Comment: Additionally, I suggest setting `IgnoreStandardErrorWarningFormat="true"` due to https://github.com/nunit/nunit-console/issues/242. Otherwise `ExitCode` might be `-1` instead of the actual exit code of the started process.