# MSVS 2015: How to get the commit id in Git using only MSVS 2015 tools

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I want to add the git commit id number into a project header file using only MSVS 2015 tools.

At the moment it is implemented with an executable running on pre-build that looks for `.git` directory and finds the appropriate file with a commit id number. It works fine but I want to use git worktrees because I have to work with multiple branches the same time and I don't really want to have multiple cloned repositories.

Is there a way to use MSVS 2015 tools to reach this goal?

Comment: What do you mean by "revision number"? The git commit id?

Comment: @Leon exactly commit id.

Comment: It's very unlikely that MSVS 2015 supports worktrees. I'd recommend running git commandline from the project. As far as I understand you can put its output to project variable like described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16804205/2303202)